# Finding largest line number using Spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am facing a problem in which i have to find out the largest line and its index. Here is my approach

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("basicavg");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile("/home/impadmin/ravi.txt");
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer,String>> words = rdd.map(new Function<String, Tuple2<Integer,String>>() {

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer,String> call(String v1) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Tuple2<Integer, String>(v1.split(" ").length, v1);
        }
    });
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> linNoToWord = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(words).sortByKey(false);

    System.out.println(linNoToWord.first()._1+"  *********************  "+linNoToWord.first()._2);
```

Comment: please describe your specific problem. Does your approach fail and how?

Comment: The problem is to find index of largest line in a file using spark along with the line.

Comment: @RaviShankar The below answer will give you line index starting from 0.

Comment: @RaviShankar Added solution for both line index and text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way the tupleRDD will get sorted on the basis of key and the first element in the new rdd after sorting is of highest length:

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile("/home/impadmin/ravi.txt");
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer,String>> words = rdd.map(new Function<String, Tuple2<Integer,String>>() {

    @Override
    public Tuple2<Integer,String> call(String v1) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Tuple2<Integer, String>(v1.split(" ").length, v1);
    }
});
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer,String>> tupleRDD1=  tupleRDD.sortBy(new Function<Tuple2<Integer,String>, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer call(Tuple2<Integer, String> v1) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v1._1;
        }
    }, false, 1);
    System.out.println(tupleRDD1.first());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concerned with the line number and text both, please try this.

First create a serializable class **Line** :

```
public static class Line implements Serializable {
    public Line(Long lineNo, String text) {
        lineNo_ = lineNo;
        text_ = text;
    }
    public Long lineNo_;
    public String text_;
}
```

Then do the following operations:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("basicavg");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile("/home/impadmin/words.txt");
    JavaPairRDD<Long, Line> linNoToWord2 = rdd.zipWithIndex().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String,Long>, Long, Line>() {
        public Tuple2<Long, Line> call(Tuple2<String, Long> t){

            return new Tuple2<Long, Line>(Long.valueOf(t._1.split(" ").length), new Line(t._2, t._1));
        }
    }).sortByKey(false);

    System.out.println(linNoToWord2.first()._1+"  *********************  "+linNoToWord2.first()._2.text_);
```